# Create a database table in Visual Studio 2015 - Wrong Build Action

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

I want to create a datatable Table1.sql in Visual Studio 2015. I use the following code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES("Mueller", "Mike", "Berlin");
```

I get the following error at the INSERT word: 
Error 70001 This statement is not recognized in this context.

When I set the Build Properties for Table1 from Build to None, the 70001 Error is gone but I get the message `Wrong Build Action` - The document's Build Action property must be set to Build for the designer to load. What can I do to create the Table1.sql?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server (you also have a mysql tag), change your double quotes to single quotes:

`INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES('Mueller', 'Mike', 'Berlin');`

Comment: The tag was wrong, but the single quotes doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you leave Build Action as `None`?

Comment: No, I set it back to `Build`.

Comment: You were right to change it to `None` because with `Build` the `INSERT` is not recognized.

Comment: But then I get the `Wrong Build Action` message again. :/

Comment: Sounds like you're not done creating the table yet.  Can you remove the `INSERT`, finish up the table and then enter a new `INSERT`?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means you started creating `Table1` in a designer and now the designer no longer loads even though you removed the `INSERT` and changed Build Action back to `Build`?

Comment: There is an empty `Table1`. When I remove `INSERT` I get the Error 80001 at the INTO tag --> Incorrect syntax near 'INTO'. (Build Action is at `Build`)

Comment: Now I understand.  I meant remove the `INSERT` statement, i.e. take out the entire line:  `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES('Mueller', 'Mike', 'Berlin');`